# mongodb c# driver is too much slow

Tags: c#, mongodb, nosql

I have data of 1700 documents in a collection.
When i get data using MongoDB Shell command.

```
db.PlayerInfo.find()
```

It takes only not more than 2 seconds to get data.
But when i do same on c# application. It takes about 8-12 seconds to get data.

```
var resultDoc = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList();

foreach (var item in resultDoc)
{

}
```

I'm using latest c# driver i.e 2.7.0 and database i'm using is 4.0.
What should i do? Do i need to do something to optimize query or it is the MongoDB C# is slow?

Comment: Are you counting the time to deserialise and display the data in both tests?

Comment: No, i had put application in debug mode. and traversing the each line so it is taking time while execute query. and it takes very minute time to serialize and display the data.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` is quite slow. Does your 8-12 seconds **include** the `Console.WriteLine` calls? Or is it **just** the first line?

Comment: No, I'm not counting that time. getting data in "resultDoc" is taking that much time.

Comment: Queries in the shell only retrieve the first batch of 20 documents, not all 1700.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Thanks for the response. Even i read this somewhere yesterday, so i guess it will take that much of time to retrieve data. But NoSql is supposed to be faster as well. I mean i have retrieve same data from mySql, when compared later retrieves data faster than former.

Comment: @HimanshuSharma, really depends on how you're retrieving it, server latency, server resources, etc. Your code `ToList()` as others pointed out retrieves all, then you iterate on it. I would suggest to create a benchmark test.